# Regex replacement, but keep contents within

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have

```
vuj(43)
```

I know I can find it with:

```
^(vuj\().+(\))$
```

or

```
vuj\(\d+\)
```

But is there any way to replace *vuj()* 
with other wrapper in **ONE** regex? Like:
*vuj[43]*

Thanks

Comment: do you mean regex replacement or you mean to have generic regex that supports ( and [ and { all in one regex is it ?

Comment: Regex replacement, replace start1-content-end1 with start2-content-end2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search by this:

```
([^(]+)\(([^)]+)\)
```

and

replace by this:

```
\1[\2]
```

[RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/tSYfWO/2)